# Matching objects of different types without violating SOLID/minimizing dependencies

Tags: c#, design, solid, single-responsibility

I have two separate inheritance hierarchies that represent objects that can be "matched" to each other to consitute a FooBarMatch (which contains references to the matched FooBase and Bar partners):

```
                          _____________
                         | FooBarMatch |
                         |-------------|
                    ---<>|FooBase      |<>---
                   |     |Bar          |     |
                   |     |_____________|     |
                   |                         |
                   |                         |
             ______|_______          ________|_____              
            | <<abstract>> |        |      Bar     |
            |    FooBase   |        |______________|
            |______________|
                   ^
                   |
         --------------------
 _______|______       _______|______
|     FooA     |     |      FooB    |
|______________|     |______________|
```

The actual logic for determining whether a `FooBase` is a match for a `Bar` depends on what subtype `FooBase` ends up being (if `FooBase` is a `FooA` we need to execute different logic than if it's a `FooB`).  But all `FooBase` objects can be compared to a `Bar` to see if they are a match.

I am currently handling this as follows: by creating an `IBarMatchable` interface with an `IsMatch(Bar) : bool` method, which is implemented by an abstract method in `FooBase`.  `FooA` and `FooB` then contain different implementations for `IsMatch(Bar)`.  It looks like this:

```
                          _____________
                         | FooBarMatch |
                         |-------------|
 _______________    ---<>|FooBase      |<>---
| IBarMatchable |  |     |Bar          |     |
|---------------|  |     |_____________|     |
| IsMatch(Bar)  |  |                         |
|_______________|  |                         |
        ^    ______|_______          ________|_____              
        |   | <<abstract>> |        |      Bar     |
         ---|    FooBase   |        |______________|
            |--------------|
            |*IsMatch(Bar)*|
            |______________|
                   ^
                   |
         --------------------
 _______|______       _______|______
|     FooA     |     |      FooB    |
|--------------|     |--------------|
|IsMatch(Bar)  |     |IsMatch(Bar)  |
|______________|     |______________|
```

Now to determine matches we can only concern ourselves with `IBarMatchable`.  This seems to accomplish what I want, however I am curious if this is "good design" or not-- I'm most concerned that it now seems to

1. Introduces a dependency on `Bar` to `FooBase` to support functionality that is ultimately outside of `FooBase` (`FooBase` itself doesn't care about matching at all).  `FooBase` otherwise has nothing to do with `Bar`.
2. Introduces a second "reason to change" (i.e. the way we define a match changes) to `FooBase`-- so potentially a SRP violation.

Does this violate SOLID?  Is there a better way to design this that does not require `FooBase` to depend on `Bar`?

Comment: What language is this in? (In some languages, a standalone polymorphic function could be used without being a part of `FooBase`)

Comment: @Telastyn -  It's C# (I just added a tag)

Comment: Then depending on the visibility of the elements used to do the match, an extension method may better decouple things.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete, real-world example?  Your foobar example doesn't really provide any insight into why you've made these particular design choices.

Comment: Without knowing how the `IsMatch` method works (at least, roughly), it is impossible to say if it is a good or bad choice to place it in the `Foo` hierarchy. Could it easily be implemented outside of `FooA` and `FooB` in terms of their public methods/properties, or does it need access to internals of those objects? Please clarify.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, the IsMatch can be implemented outside of FooA and FooB-- it does not need access to any internals of FooA or FooB; the match is determined exclusively using public properties of FooA and FooB.

Comment: @Andrew: then you have at least the opportunity to implement the method in a separate class `FooBarMatcher`, if you want to avoid to induce the dependency on `Bar`. Maybe it is possible to implement `IsMatch` using only public methods of `FooBase`. But to make a decision if that is the right choice, one needs to know the real names of your classes and the abstraction they form.

Comment: Stopped reading after: "I have two separate inheritance hierarchies..". That problem merits solving first. Use interfaces?

Comment: Down voted for the vague class descriptions, and worrying about violating "SOLID." SOLID is only a set of guidelines, and they are not all appropriate in all situations.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this:

- As mentioned in the comments: an extension method could accomplish the same thing
- If you want to continue with the interface approach but are concerned about `FooBase` having a dependency on `Bar`, you could implement the interface in `FooA` and `FooB` so that only they have a dependency on `Bar` (which is an actual dependency). Then you just work on the interface instead of on the base-class.

Either way, a lot of it depends on your actual model. In a case like this, it's better to mention the actual model rather than use `foo` and `bar`

Answer (score 1):

Put the dependency in `FooBarMatch`

Very similar to `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`, implement a `IMatcher` in `Foo` and `Bar` that returns a matcher *object* - with a `IMatchable.GetMatcher` method (and others as needed).

`IMatcher.MatchMeUP` will take a counterpart object. An `IMatcher` object will necessarily need to know intimate details to make matches. The `FooBarMatch` object needs to know what, when, how to call `IMatcher` API to make matches and do something with the results. `Foo` and `Bar` don't even need to be aware of the existence of any other classes.

However the devil is in the details and there will be design decisions as to how the `Foo` & `Bar` "native" public API and their `IMatcher` public API is manipulated in `FooBarMatch` to make the match-making happen.